# Xamarin iOS Black screen only after update UnifiedAPI. apparently all resources not loading

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin

After migrate Xamarin iOS project to Unified API, the app shows black screen only.
Apparently all resources are not loaded at all. 
Not only all images including icon, splash are not loaded, but also all XIBs are not loaded.
Now only default black window screen is shown.
Any advice to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In some cases XI 8.6.0 new msbuild-based build system can *forget* to copy some files into the app bundle.

This is fixed in the service release (8.6.1) which is in the alpha channel (right now). You might want to try it to see if this is the issue (if not then please file a bug report so it can be investigated).

Comment: if I update XI to alpha channel(8.6.1) and test, how can I back to stable(8.6.0)?

Comment: Yes, you can switch back to the **stable** channel and that will (right now) go back to 8.6.0. OTOH that's a fairly small/focused update and should be in beta, then stable, very soon. Details @ http://developer.xamarin.com/releases/ios/xamarin.ios_8/xamarin.ios_8.6/